# Что означают квадратные скобки в конце массива? PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Столкнулся вот с таким кодом:

```
$GLOBALS['status'][] = $str;
```

И не могу понять, что он делает? Интуитивно кажется, что создается глобальная переменная status в массиве $GLOBALS, после чего она сама становится массивом и первому элементу (или какому?) массива status присваивается значение $str. Правильно ли я понял, что здесь происходит?

Comment: Правильно.https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: но именно так, через $GLOBALS, никогда писать не следует. Это говнокод из прошлого века

Comment: @Ипатьев стоит использовать global? Если нет возможности обойтись локальными переменными

Comment: global это тоже самое. возможность обойтись локальными переменными всегда есть

Comment: `[]` добавляют в конец. если ранее `status` уже было объявлено, то добавится не начальный, а в конец.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ: Добавляет значение в конец массива.**

Смотрите больше тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = array('good', 'bad', 'middle');

foreach($status as $value){
    $GLOBALS['status'][] = $value;
}

echo $GLOBALS['status'][0]; // good
echo $GLOBALS['status'][1]; // bad
echo $GLOBALS['status'][2]; // middle
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]